# Leaflet - Map screenshot with imageOverlay

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to do a screenshot of my customized map. I tried several plugins like leaflet-image, html2canvas and dom-to-image but all of them failed.
In my map, I add the background in this way:

```
const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob),
     imageBounds = [
                        [0, 0],
                        [768, 1380]
                    ];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(imageBounds);
```

If I use leaflet-image it generates an image with every layer but without the background. If I use html2canvas or dom-to-image it generates an image with not only the map and layers but even with toolbar, empty spaces, etc.
There are no solutions for my case?